# HandsOnTable - How to use row header in data schema

Tags: javascript, handsontable

I need an 'id' column in my schema and I'd be happy to use the row header value for that matter, mainly for avoiding implementing a 'generating_id' functionality.
I have 5 fields in my data schema, however, I've defined only 4 columns, hoping to somehow map the row header value to the schema 'id' property, and by that avoiding creating, hiding and rendering the 'id' column.
I tried using *this.hot.getData()[row].id = this.hot.getRowHeader(row)*
but the object that *getData()* returns doesn't have the 'id' coumn.

Any ideas?

```
const hotConfig = {
        dataSchema: {id: null, name: null, sequence: null, bpLength: null, seqType: null},
        colHeaders: [NAME_COL, SEQUENCE_COL, BPLENGTH_COL, TYPE_COL],
        columns: [
            {
                data: 'name',
                validator: nameFieldValidator,
                allowInvalid: false
            },
            {
                data: 'sequence',
                validator: sequecnceFieldValidator,
                allowInvalid: true,
                width: 1000,
                maxLength: 3
            },
            {
                data: 'bpLength',
                readOnly: true
            },
            {
                data: 'seqType',
                editor: 'select',
                selectOptions: [DNA, AMINO_ACID, UNKNOWN],
                width: 100,
                readOnly: true,
                strict: true
            }
        ],

        rowHeaders: true,
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

seems like this did the trick:

```
{  

   this.hot.addHook('afterChange', this.onCellChanged.bind(this));
   :
   onCellValidated(isValid, value, row, prop, source) {

        this.hot.getSourceDataAtRow(row)[ID_COL_IDX] = this.hot.getRowHeader(row);

    }
}
```